# Contact form on fragment not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a simple feedback form on my fragment, but the app stops when I swipe to the contact tab. here is my contactfragment.java code :

```
package me.hicham.resume;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import me.hicham.resume.R;

public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {

public ContactFragment(){}
Button Send_feedback;
EditText name,email,subject,message;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

    Send_feedback = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.FeedbackButton);
    name = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.NameText);
    email = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EmailText);
    subject = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.subjecttext);
    message = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.messagetext);

    Send_feedback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String b_name = name.getText().toString();
            String b_email = email.getText().toString();
            String b_subject = subject.getText().toString();
            String b_message = message.getText().toString();

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,b_name);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ b_email});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, b_subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, b_message);

            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Typeface opensans = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");


    TextView contact1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.contact1);
    contact1.setTypeface(opensans);
    contact1.setText("Let's Talk !");

    TextView contacttext = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.contacttext);
    contacttext.setTypeface(opensans);
    contacttext.setText("\" If you want to discuss a possible project, know more about me, or just have a chitchat :) please get in touch.\"");

    EditText nametext = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.NameText);
    nametext.setTypeface(opensans);

    EditText emailtext = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EmailText);
    emailtext.setTypeface(opensans);

    EditText messagetext = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.messagetext);
    messagetext.setTypeface(opensans);  

    EditText subjecttext = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.subjecttext);
    subjecttext.setTypeface(opensans);

}

}
```

This is what Logcat says :

```
01-29 20:27:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(20311):    at me.hicham.resume.ContactFragment.onCreateView(ContactFragment.java:29)
```

Can anyone please tell me where is the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: `Send_feedback = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.FeedbackButton);` same for other views

Comment: That solved my problem ! Thanks @Raghunandan
BTW, Is it ok that my app does not have onCreate() function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO here is the solution ! might help someone :)

```
Send_feedback = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.FeedbackButton);
```

thanks to Raghunandan.